# delete file after reading into inputstream

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to retrieve a video stream from a file stored locally. After reading into an inputstream, I am trying to delete the file but it does not allow this to happen. I understand that I need to close the stream, but I need to pass this stream on to a webserver call. Any ideas on how to best approach this:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("\\Location\\file.txt");
File f = new File("\\Location\\file.txt");

             if(f.delete()) {
                System.out.println("success");
             } else {
                System.out.println("failure");
             }
```

Comment: You haven't yet read the inputstream. Just wait with the deletion until the webserver is done with the stream would be my suggestion.

Comment: in finally block you can delete the file.

Comment: Could try calling `f.deleteOnExit()` which will delete the file when the JVM terminates (which may be much later than you would ideally want to delete the file).

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens in the constructor `FileInputStream(File file)` which your constructor delegates to:

```
public FileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
   //some checks of file objects omitted here
   fd = new FileDescriptor();
   fd.attach(this);
   open(name);    //native method opening the file for reading
}
```

calling `FileInputStream.close()` releases the file descriptor created in the constructor and calls native method to close opened file.

After the call to `close()` you will be able to delete the file.

See [source here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/FileInputStream.java#FileInputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.File%29).

Answer (score 2):

Try delete on the Finally block

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

class DeleteFile extends FileInputStream {

  File file;

  public DeleteFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(new File(s));
  }

  public DeleteFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(file);
    this.file = file;
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
      super.close();
    } finally {
      if (file != null) {
        file.delete();
        file = null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks good, though it will only work if the OP remembers to actually close the InputStream.

Comment: btw the OP appears to be new to Java, so to make this answer useful you should expand on how to use this class. Also, I think it would be better named DeleteOnCloseFileInputStream. `try (InputStream is = new DeleteOnCloseFileInputStream("\\Location\\file.txt")) {...use the InputStream...}` would make sure that the InputStream gets closed (and therefore the file gets deleted) no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The f.deleteOnExit() seemed to work fine but will consider these other options

Comment: Sorry one more related question: since I do the f.deleteOnExit() outside the above method and class it works; but if I try and close the inputstream and delete the file, that works but the returned stream is null in the calling function?

Answer (score 0):

`Files.newInputStream(yourFile,StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE)` seems to be a better option.